# I am having a bug in linear-gradient that will not show the background image

Tags: css

I am having a problem where the image will not show up if I am using a linear gradient however it loads when I do a regular background and set the opacity to 0.5.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
.main{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)50%), url(background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Your syntax for linear gradient is incorrect. It needs at minimum a start and end value. You should be able to see that it is invalid by using your browser devtools inspect facility. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to add background with gradient over image.

So you are started with color missing with end color. you can have more insight with two links for basic understanding on css gradients. I hope this helps.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
.main{
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/7130560/pexels-photo-7130560.jpeg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    
  /*remove css*/
    Color: bisque;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">Some Text</div>
```